# How to use props on thirs party components that are styled?

Tags: typescript, styled-components

In multiple parts of my app I use styled-components to change the look of third-party components, like  from react-router-dom:

```
const StyledLink = styled(Link)``

// ...

<StyledLink to={'/org/' + org.id} key={org.id}>
```

It worked fine until one of the recent @types update, and now I am getting the error:

> Property 'to' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & StyledComponentPropsWithAs<any, any, object, string | number | symbol, any>'.ts(2769)

I searched through SO, GitHub issues and docs and haven't found the answer on how to get rid of that error, every other question are related to the cases when props are used inside style like `${p => p.propName}`, but in my case, those props aren't used in styles, they need to be passed to component(`Link`) in my example.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean with `recent @types update`?

Comment: @diedu I update packages from time to time, and looks like that error appeared after one of `@types/styled-components` new versions. (Or @typescript-eslint)

Comment: ok, please add the version you had before and the new version you updated to

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem with no success, check the latest versions of `@types/styled-components` and `@types/react-router-dom` are installed - https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-bhaskara-g7ush?file=/src/App.tsx